# Elasticsearch: how to get store.size and pri.store.size per day size in url query between date range

Tags: elasticsearch

I am new in elastic search so, please help me to find out the per day index store size based on date range. Currently, i have index records and total store size of the index.

Url: http://localhost:9200/_cat/indices?v&index=**index_name**

**health    index    docs.count   store.size    pri.store.size**

green    elastic_1      2345        1gb          500mb

green    elastic_2      1234        15gb         7.8gb

green    elastic_3      1222        7gb          3.7gb

Url: **http://localhost:9200/_cat/indices?bytes=b&v&index=index_name&h=store.size&format=json**

Output: [{"store.size":"122"},{"store.size":"222"},{"store.size":"333"}]

how to get per day index log message size both(**store.size** and **pri.store.size**) based on start_date(12:00AM) to end_date(11:59PM)?

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you can get the information you seek using Elastic REST API. Ideally, you should configure time based indices by using [date-math in index names](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/date-math-index-names.html) i.e. every day you will have a new index with date in the name. This way you can use CAT indices API to get per day index store size.

Alternatively, if you don't have time based indices you could do something to get a fairly approximate per day index store size. At 12:00 AM check the index store size, make a note of it and repeat the check again next day at 11:59 PM. The difference should give you the index store size for the last day.